# Custom exception name instead of UserLambdaValidationException

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use the `Pre sign-up` trigger of Cognito to validate the user registration. If some validation fails the function responses with a custom error. The client only receive the `UserLambdaValidationException` as `ErrorCode`.

Is there a way to receive the custom error name instead?

Current using sample:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {                
  function AccountAlreadyExistsError(message) {
    this.name = "AccountAlreadyExistsError";
    this.message = message;
  }
  AccountAlreadyExistsError.prototype = new Error();

  const error = new AccountAlreadyExistsError("Account is in use!");
  callback(error);
};
```

I want to get `AccountAlreadyExistsError` in our client instead of `UserLambdaValidationException`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?

Comment: Still searching for a solution. Anyone found one?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise exception headers only if it is a Lambda Proxy, with the API Gateway (x-amzn-errortype header), in any other case you need to parse the exception message to get your custom exception, here is an example how I manage exceptions for Cognito lambda triggers, it's just to show you the idea:

```
/*
  Lambda Code, could be in a Lambda layer
*/
const EXCEPTION_TYPE_DELIMITER = "etype"
const EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_DELIMITER = "emsg";

const beTagged = (tag, txt) => {
  return "<" + tag + ">" + txt + "</" + tag + ">";
};

class UserNotAllowedException extends Error {
   constructor (message) {
     super(beTagged(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_DELIMITER, message))
     Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
     this.name = beTagged(EXCEPTION_TYPE_DELIMITER, this.constructor.name);
   }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // Your logic, etc..  
    throw new UserNotAllowedException("You are blocked :(");
}
```

Here is the parser

```
/*
  Client Code
*/
const EXCEPTION_TYPE_DELIMITER_REGEX = /<etype>(.*?)<\/etype>/g;
const EXCEPTION_TYPE_UNTAG_REGEX = /<\/?etype>/g;
const EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_DELIMITER_REGEX = /<emsg>(.*?)<\/emsg>/g;
const EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_UNTAG_REGEX = /<\/?emsg>/g;

const untag = (txt, delimiterRegex, untagRegex) => {
  return txt.match(delimiterRegex).map(etype => {
    return etype.replace(untagRegex,"");
  })[0];
};

const resolveException = (exceptionMessage) => {
    const exceptionType = untag(exceptionMessage, EXCEPTION_TYPE_DELIMITER_REGEX, EXCEPTION_TYPE_UNTAG_REGEX);
    const exceptionMessage = untag(exceptionMessage, EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_DELIMITER_REGEX, EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_UNTAG_REGEX);
    // Your logic to determine what exception is the exceptionType
    return new YourResolvedException(exceptionMessage);
};

try {
   // This guy should throw the exception
   return await Auth.signUp(params);
} catch (e) {
  // Expected message from Cognito Lambda Trigger
  // PreSignUp failed with error <etype>UserNotAllowedException</etype>: <emsg>You are blocked :(</emsg>.
  // For example, here your custom exception resolver
  throw resolveException(e.message);
}
```

It can be done in a thousand ways, but the best thing for us would be if the AWS services were able to fully customise the exceptions without so much hassle.

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

I tried it on my end and was able to get the error message in the client. Tested it using AWS CLI, Nodejs & the built-in Cognito UI. I returned the error using:

```
var error = new Error('something went wrong..!');
callback(error,event);
```

I got the error `UserLambdaValidationException: PreSignUp failed with error something went wrong..!` in all my clients. Even `callback(error)` worked.

Comment: I would even suggest that if you want to send some payload (for instance validation related), you could JSON.stringify your error object with its payload and send `callback(new Error(stringifiedError), event)` to get access to your data

Comment: Overloading the message to include data is incredibly flimsy, but alas it seems like it's the only way at present.